# Web application in a Windows home network

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8

I have an application installed on Windows 8 (*pc-one*) running in localhost at `http://127.0.0.1:8000`.

Now I want to access this application from a second PC (*pc-two*) in my home network. What are the steps to follow?

- The application is built in [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com);
- The server (*pc-one*) is also running [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com);

Until now, I've only configured the homegroup to access some directories.

Comment: In most cases you can reach `pc-one` from `pc-two` by opening page  with URL `http://pc-one/` on `pc-two`

Comment: In your case (with non standard port) it is `http://pc-one:8000`

Comment: The Windows firewall needs to be OFF or allowing port 8000 in.  Additionally the app must be fully network aware, not just local host "127.0.0.1" aware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com) related question except for the first 3 steps:

- Turn off Windows Firewall;
- Find *pc-one* IP Address typing `ipconfig` in Command Prompt;
- From *pc-two* open page `http://pc-one` or `http://196.168.1.100` where `196.168.1.100` is your IP Address.

Now you can access all *pc-one* websites in `www` directory.

- From the application directory in *pc-one* run `python manage.py runserver 192.168.1.100:8000` where `196.168.1.100` is your IP Address;
- From *pc-two* open page `http://196.168.1.100:8000`.

Now you can access the application from *pc-two*.

Answer (score 0):

There are three things you need to do:

1. Find the IP address of *pc-one*. If it's on a home network, it will likely start with `192.168.`. Other possibilities are `10.` and `172.16.`.
2. Make sure the application is listening on either `0.0.0.0` or the IP address from above. This could be called the bind address or the listen address. The application may have multiple, in which case only one must necessarily be either your IP or `0.0.0.0`.
3. Feel free to test now after restarting the application. A Windows Firewall dialog will likely appear, in which you need to allow the application. If you are unable to access it from another computer with `192.168.1.2:8000` (replace `192.168.1.2` with your real IP), go to the Windows Firewall settings and allow port `8000` incoming.